# Adding list item to JList from another JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have the following code working

`made_list.setListData(original_list.getSelectedValues());`

here made_list is one JList and original_list is another JList. If i run with this code the selected value from original_list is replacing the previous value in made_list. I dont want that. i want to append instead.. How do i do this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1) Get the model for made_list
2) Get the selected items from orig_list
3) Make a new object[] that is the size of 1) + 2)
4) populate 3) with the items from 1) + 2)
5) set the make_list model with the object[] from 4)
```

Implementation:

```
ListModel made_model = made_list.getModel(); // 1

Object[] orig_sel = orig_list.getSelectedItems(); // 2

Object[] new_made_model = new Object[made_model.size() + orig_sel.length]; // 3

// this block is 4
int i = 0;
for(;i < made_model.size(); i++) 
    new_made_model[i] = made_model.getElementAt(i);
for(; i < new_made_model.length; i++) 
    new_made_model[i] = orig_sel[i - made_model.size());

made_model.setListData(new_made_model); // 5
```